# sending messages between clients in Android p2p wifi-direct

Tags: android, p2p, wifi-direct

If there are three devices A,B and C are connected using Wifi-direct , assuming B is Group Owner.

How can A sends messages to C?On running the Android wifi direct demo ,I noticed that A and C knows about B's IP address.

There is no method avialable to get the IP address of A and C.

To create a small chat application Do I need to create a server at B(Group Owner) ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll need to create a server at B.

When you create a group, the only IP address anybody knows is the group owner.  If you want A and C to communicate, you'll need to have them send their IP addresses to B, then B can send C's address to A and vice-versa.

It's kinda gross.  I'm trying to solve this problem too.

I'm thinking that the [regular NSD protocol](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html) might be promising, but I'm not sure if it will work over wifi direct.